# Is there a new system of scene unlock hints in Tiny Death Star?

Tags: ios, star-wars-tiny-death-star

I was quite busy the last couple of days, so I didn't visit the game for a long time. So, at first I got the usual message about me having to return to the Death Star. But then, less than a day after, I got this message

[image: Hint]

It obviously refers to the Cloud City Spa Solo/Fett scene. It is already unlocked on my phone, so it means that these hints are chosen randomly.

Was an update for iOS 7 released or something? I have iOS 6 and I didn't find it among my app updates.

Has the game suddenly started bringing out new hints and notifiers?

Also I got a message about VIPs' prices being reduced, but nothing happened in my TDS neither in the Arrivals level, nor in the Store

Answer (score 1):

This is a new feature of the game.  The app itself has not been updated, it is still the same version.  Rather, it seems that they are pushing out an in-game feature through their own servers.  And, a variety of new ads and notifiers have been coming out.

The VIP price has been reduced temporarily.  This is when you go into the arrivals screen and buy a Random VIP (Supply Officer, etc.).  This does not refer to bitizens that you can purchase.

Comment: It seems like prices didn't change for me, it's all as always: 1 Bux for the first slot, 2 for the second, 3 for the third, etc. I checked out all slots

Comment: I'm pretty sure that those ARE reduced prices, but it's been quite a while since I've looked at them.  They may have been reduced for quite some time, but the notifier just started coming out.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't provide any proof, but I am 90% sure they were the same for me before

Comment: @ugh Current pricing for me starts @2 Bux and goes up from there.

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently on version 1.2.2344 right now on iOS 6. I don't see a new version update available on the App Store currently. I don't think the game can auto-update itself without the App Store.

However, I did notice that the in-game ads have become a bit more obnoxious over the past day or so - they're completely full screen now, as opposed to before when they were just a small box in the middle.

Comment: Yes, I have the same verison. I meant, maybe something changed for 1.7, but not for 1.6, so I got only notifications. Did you change something in your notification center? It is the only place where you can change notifications' size I can currently think of

Comment: I haven't noticed any changes in the notification, although I am using it daily at the moment. I haven't made any changes in the Notification Center, although I thought the only thing you can control is if an app can show badges, pop-ups and sounds - not frequency or size of the notification. The ad, however, is in-game, so I don't think those are controlled by Notification Center.

Comment: Ah, so you are talking about in-game advertisement? Not just stuff like 'Mos Espa Cafe needs your attention'? I've never seen any advertisement in the game, only this long damn annoying part with Palpatin telling me about my finances

Comment: Wait, nevermind, a giant ad of an elevator just appeared on my screen.